# Bat file or Other way to create mapped drive and rename them

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a bat file already with my mapped drive info, but is there a way to have the bat rename the drives so when the how up in "my computer" they will be labeled properly?

Comment: What do you mean labeled properly? The drive label is the share name it's mapped to isn't it?

Comment: You know how you can right click and rename the drive....kinda wanna do that, the shared name isn't exactly what I want it to show.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/198499/change-network-drive-label-by-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can use comobject like this (powershell code):

```
$desc=  "MyNetworkshare" # This is the label for your unit
$mDrive =  "H:\" #this is your unit (any letter you have..)
$oShell = new-Object -com Shell.Application
$oShell.NameSpace($mDrive).Self.Name = $Desc
```